# Object count in template tags

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I created a custom simple tag that counts an object and returns it. I want the count to be shown inside the navbar. So the user can be notified.

1. I made a template tag and registered it
2. I loaded the tag inside the base.html
3. I used the tag inside the navbar, Since I want the count to be shown there.
4. It only filters through objects that have the field "live" on false
5. I created a templatetags directory inside the the application directory.
6. I added a __ init __.py inside templatetags

**notifications.py (templatetags/notifications.py)**

```
from django import template
from home.models import ReportRequests

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def new_notification(request):
    a = ReportRequests.objects.filter(live=False).count()
    return a
```

**base.html**

```
{% load notifications %}

<a href="{% url 'home:report_request' %}"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i><p>Requests</p><span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ new_notification }}</span></a>
```

I expect that the count will be shown next to the text, inside badge with bootstrap. But its not showing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few simple mistakes are there in your code.

Now, just follow the below steps to fix this.

1. Replace `{{ new_notification }}` with `{% new_notification %}` in **base.html**.

   > **Note:** `{{ template_context_variable }}` syntax is used to use value of template context variables. So use `{% template_tag params %}` syntax. Based on your Django version check the related documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ (select specific version from very bottom-right).
2. Replace `def new_notification(request):` with `def new_notification():` from **notifications.py** as you are not passing any extra parameter to the function while using template tag in template `base.html`.

Now, refresh your page and you can see the result and it is working, in my case.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I used the template tags the wrong way. Have a nice day!